# how to make workers respawn for every task?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

**Context:**

I have a set of tasks that I can easily parallelize using `mclapply` or `foreach`. Each task is computationally and memory intensive and independent of each other.

Unfortunately there is a memory leak - the garbage collection does not work properly. The memory get fragmented. I was able to mitigate it, but the leak is still there and I gave up on solving it completely (which is a softer way of saying I got defeated, and I have no hope of solving it).

My current strategy is to split my `n` tasks to `k` batches, each the size of my number of cores. So each time `mclapply` or `foreach` gets a batch of tasks the size of the number of cores, terminate all the workers, and start again.

The disadvantage of this approach is that the computational time is heterogenous and unpredictable, so I find myself waiting for 2 tasks to finish, while the other cores are idle. It will take days instead of hours to complete this way.

**Question:**
Is there a way, library or functionality, that tells `mclapply` ,`foreach`, `parLapply` etc to get a new worker for each new job and terminate it once it is done?

This is an ubuntu machine.

Comment: I believe yes. Check out the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) package which is a much more robust and comprehensive framework for parallelization in R.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this level of control can be obtained using the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) and [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply/index.html) packages. The `future.apply` package replicates the base *apply family of functions in parallel. Specifically, `future_lapply` is the corollary to `lapply` and is the more advanced predecessor of `parallel::mclapply`. It gives pretty fine-grained control over how the `futures` (in your case the `n` tasks) are evaluated. Specifically addressing your question, `future_lapply` provides the `future.scheduling` argument, which when set to `FALSE` ensures that each task is evaluated in a fresh R session. We can verify that this is true by initially setting `future.scheduling = TRUE`:

```r
future::plan("multisession")

invisible(
  future.apply::future_lapply(
    1:16,
    function(i) {
      tryCatch(
        {
          get("a", envir = globalenv())
          cat("`a` now exists in R session on", Sys.getpid(), "\n")
        },
        error = function(e) {
          cat("`a` does not yet exist in R session on", Sys.getpid(), "\n")
        }
      )
      assign("a", 1, envir = globalenv())
    }, 
    future.scheduling = TRUE
  )
)
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 4388 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 4388 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 12032 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 12032 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 5656 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 5656 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 3800 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 3800 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 5940 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 5940 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 7724 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 7724 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 17328 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 17328 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 23492 
#> `a` now exists in R session on 23492
```

What this does is uses a 16-element list (my machine has 8 cores) and maps across this list in parallel. This list is chopped up equally meaning each future handles 2 items in the list. After processing the first element, I assign a variable named `a` in the global environment and, when processing the second element, I check to make sure that `a` exists and can be accessed. For each of the 8 futures, we can see that it successfully assigns `a` into the global environment when processing the first list element and can access it again when processing the second list element. In other words, each of the 2 items in each future is processed in the same (potentially cluttered) environment. However, when we set `future.scheduling = FALSE`:

```r
future::plan("multisession")

invisible(
  future.apply::future_lapply(
    1:16,
    function(i) {
      tryCatch(
        {
          get("a", envir = globalenv())
          cat("`a` now exists in R session on", Sys.getpid(), "\n")
        },
        error = function(e) {
          cat("`a` does not yet exist in R session on", Sys.getpid(), "\n")
        }
      )
      assign("a", 1, envir = globalenv())
    }, 
    future.scheduling = FALSE
  )
)
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 18976 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 18292 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 21812 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 1700 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 21780 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 17712 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 9252 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 19336 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 18976 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 18292 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 21812 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 1700 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 21780 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 17712 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 9252 
#> `a` does not yet exist in R session on 19336
```

As we can see, each list element is now being processed in a separate, clean R session.

## TLDR

If you have a list that you want to be executed on in parallel where each element is processed in its own, clean R session do the following workflow:

```r
library(future)
library(future.apply)

your_list <- list("of", "n", "chunks")
your_function <- function(i) print(i)

future_lapply(
  your_list,
  your_function,
  future.scheduling = FALSE
)
#> [1] "of"
#> [1] "n"
#> [1] "chunks"
```

I'm really not sure if this answers your question or problem, but hopefully it gets you on the right track!

Comment: Use `plan(future.callr::callr)` instead. That'll give you a new R process for every future.  `plan(multisession)` sets up the workers once, and re-uses them.